# C# - SQLDataReader by Index vs. SQLDataReader.GetOrdinal(ColumnName)

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, ado.net, sqldatareader

Is one considered better standard? Is one quicker than the other? Or, is just mainly preference? **GetOrdinal** is nice because you can call the column name out itself and not have to worry about counting the index of the fields in SQL, but I would like to know if there are benefits using one over the other.

**Reading by Index:**

```
            while (reader.Read())
            { 
                Column1 = reader.GetValue(0).ToString().Trim();
                Column2 = reader.GetValue(1).ToString().Trim();
            }
```

**Reader.GetOrdinal:**

```
           while (reader.Read())
           {
               data.Column1 = reader.GetValue(reader.GetOrdinal("COLUMN1")).ToString();
               data.Column2 = reader.GetValue(reader.GetOrdinal("COLUMN2")).ToString();
               data.Column3 = reader.GetDateTime(reader.GetOrdinal("COLUMN3"));
           }
```

Comment: Reading by index is faster. `GetOrdinal` needs to compare strings which is not so fast as acessing array elements by index.

Comment: I figured reading by index is faster, but I have had some devs literally insist that GetOrdinal is "better standard". My current job we are all about speed so it makes sense our lead wants us to read by index. My last job insisted using GetOrdinal was better for some reason. Good to know!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[reader.GetOrdinal(string)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getordinal?view=netframework-4.8) will get the column ordinal, given the name of the column

We can see `GetOrdinal` sourcecode from [SqlDataReader](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/fx/src/data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlDataReader.cs,d66096b6f57cac74) it will return a index from `_fieldNameLookup.GetOrdinal` (`_fieldNameLookup` field is a `FieldNameLookup` class)

> `_fieldNames` is a hashtable stores the index, match via case-sensitive

```
override public int GetOrdinal(string name) {
    SqlStatistics statistics = null;
    try {
        statistics = SqlStatistics.StartTimer(Statistics);
        if (null == _fieldNameLookup) {
            CheckMetaDataIsReady();
            _fieldNameLookup = new FieldNameLookup(this, _defaultLCID);
        }
        return _fieldNameLookup.GetOrdinal(name); // MDAC 71470
    }
    finally {
        SqlStatistics.StopTimer(statistics);
    }
}
```

we can see the source code `GetOrdinal` method from `FieldNameLookup` class.

```
public int GetOrdinal(string fieldName) { // V1.2.3300
    if (null == fieldName) {
        throw ADP.ArgumentNull("fieldName");
    }
    int index = IndexOf(fieldName);
    if (-1 == index) {
        throw ADP.IndexOutOfRange(fieldName);
    }
    return index;
}

public int IndexOf(string fieldName) { // V1.2.3300
    if (null == _fieldNameLookup) {
        GenerateLookup();
    }
    int index;
    object value = _fieldNameLookup[fieldName];
    if (null != value) {
        // via case sensitive search, first match with lowest ordinal matches
        index = (int) value;
    }
    else {
        // via case insensitive search, first match with lowest ordinal matches
        index = LinearIndexOf(fieldName, CompareOptions.IgnoreCase);
        if (-1 == index) {
            // do the slow search now (kana, width insensitive comparison)
            index = LinearIndexOf(fieldName, ADP.compareOptions);
        }
    }
    return index;
}
```

> Is one quicker than the other?

If you already know columns exist index number `reader.GetValue(0)` will faster then `reader.GetValue(reader.GetOrdinal("COLUMN1"))` becuase it didn't cause resource to get the colunm index from `reader.GetOrdinal` method.

> Is one considered better standard?

There isn't comparison standard because of  `reader.GetValue(0)` and  `reader.GetValue(reader.GetOrdinal("COLUMN1"))` are doing the same thing, as before answer.

`reader.GetValue(reader.GetOrdinal("COLUMN1"))` be better reading then  `reader.GetValue(0)`, because columns name will be better to know instead index.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer! Now it makes sense why we read by index at my current job (for speed), but used GetOrdinal at my last job (standard/didn't care about speed). It sucks when you're adding a new field in a big query and have to redo all of the indexes but it's worth it if makes your execution quicker.

Comment: @AndrewReese No problem glad to help

Answer (score 2):

I always use function that returns dictionary with columns names as key and index as value, like that one:

```
public IDictionary<string, int> GetColumnNames(ref SqlDataReader reader) {
    IDictionary<string, int> dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    if (reader == null)
        return dict;
    int columns = reader.FieldCount;

    for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
        dict[reader.GetName(i)] = i;
    }

    return dict;
}
```

then you can just create new object an call any time:

```
var cols = GetColumnNames(ref r);
while (r.Read())
    var value = r.GetInt32(cols["SOME_COLUMN"]);
```

I don't really know if it's quicker, but works for me.
Also, works nice with defined constant column names.

Comment: I've never seen it used that way, but very interesting. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: YW. It still is slower than just calling index, but you get columns stored once what is salutary with dozens or hundreds of rows.